# Ventana ocupa mayor espacio que la resolución al maximizar

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf

He creado una ventana en WPF que hace uso de `WindowChrome`, con el fin de personalizar el marco de la ventana sin perder algunas características y rendimiento de la aplicación.

Todo funciona bien, excepto al momento de maximizar la ventana, y es que esta ocupa un tamaño mayor al de la resolución de la pantalla, en mi caso, la resolución es de **1440x900 píxeles** y la ventana al ser maximizada consigue un tamaño de **1456x916 píxeles**, 16 píxeles de más que no deberían estar. Esto lo he comprobado utilizando el Explorador de propiedades dinámico.

Aclaro que este problema no ocurre únicamente con WindowChrome, de hecho pasa lo mismo al establecer la propiedad `ResizeMode = CanResizeWithGrip`.

Además, he solucionado el problema de forma temporal utilizando el siguiente código al utilizar el botón de maximizado o haciendo doble click sobre la barra de título. Aclaro que la solución que he implementado funciona bien, pero existe un detalle, no funciona al momento de maximizar la ventana con atajos de teclado, es decir, utilizar **Windows + Flecha Arriba**. Al hacerlo, entonces la ventana ocupa el espacio adicional que mencioné anteriormente.

**CÓDIGO XAML**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        xmlns:ewt="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlackXells.Locker.UI"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:BlackXells.Locker.Controls"
        x:Class="BlackXells.Locker.UI.Dashboard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Locker" MinHeight="550" MinWidth="950" Height="525" Width="1022" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="/Locker;component\Resources\locker-logo.ico">

    <!--Soporte de shell de Windows-->
    <shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <shell:WindowChrome x:Name="gui_shell" CaptionHeight="0" CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="0" ResizeBorderThickness="6"/>
    </shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="#FFC8C8C8" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="_titlebarContainer" Height="42">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="0"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Border x:Name="TitleBar" Background="WhiteSmoke" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" CornerRadius="0" Height="42" MouseLeftButtonDown="TitleBar_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<!--Botones de modificación de la ventana-->
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button x:Name="_btn_titlebar_minimize" Click="_defaults_window_minimize" Style="{StaticResource titlebar.buttons.minimize}" Margin="0,0,7,0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="_btn_titlebar_maximize_restore" Click="_defaults_window_maximize_restore" Style="{StaticResource titlebar.buttons.maximize}" Margin="0,0,7,0" />
                    <Button x:Name="_btn_titlebar_close" Click="_defaults_window_close" Style="{StaticResource titlebar.buttons.close}" Margin="0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

**CÓDIGO C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using WF = System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BlackXells.Locker.UI
{
    public partial class Dashboard : Window
    {
        public Dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _defaults_window_location();
        }

        #region WINDOW SUPPORT
        // método de cierre de la ventana
        private void _defaults_window_close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Close();
        //método de maximización y restauración de la ventana
        private void _defaults_window_maximize_restore(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ChangeWindowState(!_IsMaximized ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal);
        // método de maximizado de la ventana
        private void _defaults_window_minimize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

        //obtiene un valor que determina si la ventana se encuentra maximizada
        private bool _IsMaximized { get; set; } = false;
        //_windowLocationX y _windowLocationY se utilizan para guardar las cordenadas de la ventana en el escritorio.
        //_windowSizeWidth y _windowSizeHeight se utilizan para guardar el tamaño de la ventana.
        private int _windowLocationX, _windowLocationY, _windowSizeWidth, _windowSizeHeight;

        // método para arrastrar la ventana, si se hace doble click, se llama la función de maximizado
        private void TitleBar_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_IsMaximized)
                DragMove();
            if (e.ClickCount == 2)
                ChangeWindowState(!_IsMaximized ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal);
        }

        // almacena temporalmente las cordenadas de la ventana y el tamaño de la misma al momento de maximizar
        private void _defaults_window_location()
        {
            _windowLocationX = (int)Left;
            _windowLocationY = (int)Top;
            _windowSizeHeight = (int)ActualHeight;
            _windowSizeWidth = (int)ActualWidth;
        }

        // Cambia el estado de la ventana maximizado/restaurado.
        private void ChangeWindowState(WindowState state)
        {
            // gui_shell -> instancia de WindowChrome para la personalización de la ventana.

            switch (state) {
                case WindowState.Maximized:
                    _defaults_window_location();

                    Width = WF_SCREEN.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
                    Height = WF_SCREEN.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
                    gui_shell.ResizeBorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                    LayoutRoot.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                    Top = 0;
                    Left = 0;
                    _IsMaximized = true;
                    break;
                case WindowState.Normal:
                    Width = _windowSizeWidth;
                    Height = _windowSizeHeight;
                    gui_shell.ResizeBorderThickness = new Thickness(6);
                    LayoutRoot.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                    Top = _windowLocationY;
                    Left = _windowLocationX;
                    _IsMaximized = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }    
}
```

Para que quede más claro, aquí dejo capturas de pantalla.

P.D.: Estoy utilizando el `WindowChrome` que se encuentra por defecto en `PresentationFramework`.

**Aquí una explicación gráfica del problema, y lo que necesito.**

[image: Problema vs. Error]

Esta es una captura de la esquina superior derecha de la ventana en estado maximizado, como es posible observar, en la primera imágen, no se puede ver una parte de la ventana, mientras que en la otra se ve la totalidad, lo cual estoy buscando.

Comment: No veo la diferencia, puedes colocar screenshots donde se indique más claramente que es lo que te esta sucediendo?

Comment: @JuanK he editado el artículo para una mayor claridad. Básicamente cierta cantidad de píxeles no son visibles, ya que la ventana llega a ocupar un tamaño mayor al de la resolución máxima de la pantalla.

Comment: Una imagen vale más que mil palabras, pero unas líneas de código valen más que mil imágenes a la hora de solucionar un problema de programación. Si pudieras añadir parte del código o un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) sería genial. ¿Hay algún sitio en el código donde se especifique un margen de 8 ó 16 píxeles?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he agregado parte del código fuente y algunas detalles más.

Comment: Quitando las propiedades Height="525" Width="1022" de Window también se ajustará a tu pantalla sin necesidad de código C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yo he solucionado mis problemas con respecto a wpf y la resolucion usando el codigo siguiente:

```
this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
```

ponlo en el constructor de la ventana, asi el tamaño maximo sera siempre tu resolucion y no mayor.

Comment: Gracias por compartir